# showing x axis label for each graph in plotly subplot with shared x axis

Tags: javascript, plot, graph, plotly, multiple-axes

I have created a subplot with plotly.JS , x axis is shared for each graph as given in the below picture.
[image: shared x axis]

I want to show the x axis values for all graphs in the subplot instead for showing it only for graph at bottom. I achieved this using anchor attribute, but the graphs are not aligned well. Look at the below picture, here 600 of graph2 is not positioned exactly to the other two graphs.
[image: without sharing xaxis]

I want all the graph to share x axis as well as show the x axis values on each graph.

Comment: Wouldn't it the easiest to use the 2nd example but with a fixed range for all 3 axes?

Comment: yes but is there any attribute to do like that. Because, my x axis is keep changing and so range will vary over time. It is more more complex to calculate the range for each set.